"ldr =" on MacOS. Static vs dynamic Linking
This is a follow up to this question.
I understand that when programming arm64 on MacOs, I can't write:
    .text
    ldr  X0, =my_string

    .data
my_string:
    .asciz "Hello There"

but instead need to change the ldr to be:
    adrp, X0, my_string@PAGE
    add   X0, X0, my_string@PAGEOFF

For a normal non-MacOs loader, the first would be turned into:
    ldr   X0, fakeLabel
    ...
fakeLabel: .quad my_string

and then the value at fakeLabel would be fixed at link time.
Meanwhile for both MacOs and non-MacOs, the linker would need the difference between the page that the ldrp is on and that my_string is one and put that delta into the ldrp instruction.
According to the answer I was given on the other page, the former is "dynamic" loading and thus illegal, while the later is "static" loading and legal.  I'm not sure I understand the difference, since both involve changing instructions.  Is the delta between the ldrp and the my_string somehow fixed?  Are text and data always loaded a certain distance apart, even though we don't know where they'll be loaded?
Am I missing something? Is this documented?

The problem isn't with instructions - all of the instruction modifications happen at link-time (=static). None of that is a problem, at link-time you can do whatever you want.
The problem lies with fakeLabel. There's a pointer stored there. Pointers need to be rebased at runtime (=dynamic) due to ASLR. If you are currently in the .text segment and you write ldr xN, =..., then the fakeLabel inserted by the compiler will also be in the .text segment. When the process is launched, the dynamic linker will dutifully try and rebase the pointer there, but since the segment is mapped as readonly, doing so will crash the process.
This would not be an issue if fakeLabel was emitted in the data segment, but since PC-relative ldr has a maximum offset of ±1MiB, and since the linker is free to rearrange segments as needed, this is not possible in the general case. It would have to emit adrp+ldr and have the linker fix it back up to PC-relative ldr if possible, but the compiler is not allowed to turn one instruction into two, and if you're using two instructions manually... well, then you might as well go for adrp+add right away and avoid the implicit pointer.

I'm not completely sure you're understanding my question (and why i created a new question.  The assembled adrp instruction includes within itself the delta between the current page and the page that the target label is on.  If the target label changes pages, then the adrp instruction needs to be changed.  Are we guaranteed that the delta between the adrp instruction and the target is fixed at link time (even though their actual addresses may change)?  Are we guaranteed that the offset within a page of a label is fixed?   Is this how it works?  If not, we'd be modifying ro code.

Yes. At least for arm64, the delta of any PC-relative instruction is fixed at link-time, segments of the same binary retain the relative position they are assigned at link-time, and the dynamic linker doesn't ever modify any instructions.

Many other linkers, especially when producing shared libraries, don't guarantee that segments are loaded at fixed offsets from each other. I suppose Apple needed to force the issue in order to get signed code.

@FrankYellin so you're saying many linkers produce binaries that can have different/independent ASLR slides applied to their .text and .data segments? And they put all the required metadata into binaries so that dynamic linkers can fix up instructions at runtime to account for that?

You're right.  I may just be confusing the elf format of a .o file with the elf format of a .so.  Let me look some more.
